# Firebase database rules. How to secure a node from being deleted with .set(null) call

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this data structure.

```
root
    -foo
        -key0
            -bar1:baz1
            -bar2:baz2
        -key1
            -bar1:baz1
            -bar2:baz2
```

And I have this rules structure.

```
"foo":{
  ".read":true,
  ".write":"auth != null",
  ".validate":"newData.hasChildren(['bar1', 'bar2'])"
}
```

But when I tried to do this `firebase.database().ref('/foo').remove()` or this `firebase.database().ref('/foo').set(null);` on the javascript console, the `.validate` on rules is not being respected and the data on the `foo` node is being deleted.

Hod do I secure database nodes that are not associated to a certain user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent `/foo` from being removed, you can check that `newData.val()` is not `null`:

```
"foo": {
  ...
  ".write": "(auth != null) && (newData.val() != null)",
  ...
}
```

Comment: So am not gonna use `".validate"` ?

Comment: It worked but isn't it weird? Or am I the one that's weird thinking this approach is weird?

Comment: I guess the `.validate` can stay, if you are using it. I suppose it's not used when deleting, otherwise it would not be possible to delete paths that had `.validate` defined.

Comment: From the docs: "Note: The `.validate` rules are only evaluated for non-null values and do not cascade."

Comment: That last quote from the documentation is indeed key, find it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-validation). Deleting data does not trigger validation rules. So to prevent deletion, you must always implement a write rule.

Answer (score 2):

Validation step is completely skipped because write was allowed.

> Note: The **.validate** rules are only evaluated for non-null values and do not cascade.

Read the following section with great useful video from firebase documentation for securing your data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

You should modify your rules.

```
"foo":{
  ".read":true,
  ".write":"auth != null && newData.exists()",
  ".validate":"newData.hasChildren(['bar1', 'bar2'])"
}
```